# How do I open .jpg file in external application

Tags: vb.net, photoshop, launching-application

So what I'm trying to do is open some images in Photoshop on the press of a button. I can get PS to launch without an issue but it just sits there waiting and does not open the file I am requesting (regardless of format (.png .jpg. bmp etc)).

I have added the Photoshop Object Library through the Add Reference Manager, but I keep getting the following error...

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast COM object of type 'Photoshop.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Photoshop._Application'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{5DE90358-4D0B-4FA1-BA3E-C91BBA863F32}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).'

All I'm wanting to do is open a series of image files from a listBox but I cannot even open an external image file. Any help would be much appreciated.

This is what I am trying...

```
Dim PSD_App As Photoshop.Application
Dim PSD_Doc As Photoshop.Document

Private Sub OpenInPS_btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OpenInPS_btn.Click
    PSD_App = New ApplicationClass
    PSD_Doc = PSD_App.Open("E:\TestImageConverter\TestImage.jpg")
End Sub
```

Thanks for taking the time to look.

Comment: Guessing you don't have Option Strict turned on, you should.  That aside, think the message gives a fair hint as to the problem.  An ApplicationClass instance can not be assigned to a Photoshop.Application instance.  Are you sure ApplicationClass is correct in that context?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to open a file in VB with photoshop:

```
Dim appRef, sampleDoc
Set appRef = CreateObject( "Photoshop.Application" )

' Switch off any dialog boxes
 appRef.displayDialogs = 3 

' Bring to front
appRef.BringToFront

sampleDoc = "E:/TestImageConverter/TestImage.jpg"
appRef.Open sampleDoc
```